# Classes deleting Variables? iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, variables

I have been having some problems with some variables inside a class being deleted lately.
Here is how I declare:

```
MyClass *myClass;
-(void)viewDidLoad {
myClass = [MyClass new];
//something using my class
```

then when I call a function later that uses an array and a dictionary inside the class.

```
[myClass doSomething];
```

Here is the code I get in the console.

```
-[CFArray objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5d1f370
```

Here is how I declare the area in the Class

```
NSArray *myArray;
-(void)doSomething{
myArray = [NSArray array];
```

Then later I just perform a valid objectAtIndex on the array. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you aren't retaining the objects, so by the time you actually use them they are deallocated, since they are auto-released. Either use synthesized properties or add a retain message to each initialization, i.e., `[[NSArray array] retain]` and `[[MyClass new] retain]`, be sure to `release` when appropriate. I recommend using properties instead though, it's cleaner.

**EDIT**: Thanks to imaginaryboy: the `[NSArray array]` call releases an autoreleased object, so you have to retain that, by changing it to `[NSArray new]` for example. Leave `[MyClass new]` as it already returns a retained object.

Comment: The array is the only thing that is the problem. [NSArray array] returns an autoreleased object. [MyClass new] returns an object that has already been retained.  So leave the [MyClass new] alone, and swap the [NSArray array] for either @Blaenk's suggestion of [[NSArray array] retain] or more usually [NSArray new] or [NSArray alloc] init].

Comment: thanks for the clarification imaginaryboy, I'll add it into my response

Comment: I do this in my interface.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myArray;

Comment: I think it could also be a about where and how I am defining a variable. How would you guys define a variable that you needed for the lifetime of a class. In what blocks would decelerations and initialization be in?

Comment: Thanks both of you for helping.

Comment: for the lifetime of the object (I assume you mean object and not class, since a class does not 'live' like an object does), you are doing it correctly. an instance variable in other words, in the interface.